# Angular update returns a dependency error

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to update my angular project, and ng update @angular/core drops the following error:

```
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 41 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler-cli @ "11.0.7" (was "10.1.6")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/animations @ "11.0.7" (was "10.1.6")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "11.0.7" (was "10.1.6")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler @ "11.0.7" (was "10.1.6")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "11.0.7" (was "10.1.6")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser @ "11.0.7" (was "10.1.6")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "11.0.7" (was "10.1.6")...
  UPDATE package.json (1654 bytes)
| Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@10.1.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^11.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/animations@"^11.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-11T15_58_29_106Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
× Migration failed. See above for further details.
```

`ng update @angular/core --force` returns the same error.

I've tried to install `@angular/animations@11.0.7` manually, but it returns the same error.

What should I do?

Thank for the advices in advance!

Comment: did you try `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` ?

Comment: I tried it now. Now I no longer see the error, however `ng update` still shows that @angular/core is still on 10.1.6. If I run `ng update @angular/core` again it says it's up to date, but running ng update again will show the same 10.1.6 version. -.-

Comment: try `ng update @angular/core@11.0.7` (if you want that version)

Comment: According to the update command it's already on that versions. However running `ng update` shows that it's still on 10.1.6... I don't understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: this one is the ultimate solution